# Formatting values from a list

Tags: c#, list, loops, formatting

Before getting into C# I used to study Python. I did this small project where the program makes a list and whatever you type it is added to the list. I tried to do the same in C# as a form of practice, but I seem to be doing something, if not everything, for the program won't work. This is my code:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic:

class idk
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<string> list = new List<string>();
        for ( ; true; )
        {
            Console.Write("Tell me something: ");
            var inp = Console.ReadLine();
            list.Add(inp);
            var i = 1;

            foreach (string a in list)
            var ni = i + 1;
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}. {1}", ni, a));
        }
    }
}
```

So I want my program to take the input, save it in the list, and then print the list but in the form of (e.g.)

1. Idk
2. C
3. A

Like an actual list, where you number each item and all that. So I tried to do the same I did in Python:

```py
List = []
while True:
    item = input("Tell me something: ")
    List.append(item)
    i = 1
    for val in List:
    print(f"{i}. {val}")
    i += 1
```

Is there something I can edit from my code to make it do the same? Or perhaps I may need to rewrite the whole thing? Thanks for your help.

Comment: "the program won't work" - how so? What does it currently do?

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; ++i) Console.WriteLine($"{i + 1}. {list[i]}");`

Comment: The program couldn't work, as `Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}. {1}", ni, a));` doesn't compile given that `ni` was instantiated and discarded given the missing brackets in the `foreach` statement

Comment: Side note: `for ( ; true; )` is a bit unusual; `while(true)` or `for(;;)` are much more common versions of infinite loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest loop type changing from `foreach` to `for`:

```
  for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; ++i)
    Console.WriteLine($"{i + 1}. {list[i]}");
```

If you insist on `foreach`:

```
  int index = 0;

  foreach (var item in list) 
    Console.WriteLine($"{++index}. {item}");
```

You can print the list in one go with a help of `Join` (to join list's items) and *Linq* (to query the list):

```
  Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, list
    .Select((value, index) => $"{index + 1}. {value}")));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should only print the contents of the list at the end when the user has decided they don't want to enter anything anymore:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class MainClass {
    public static void Main (string[] args) {
        List<string> strList = new List<string>();
        
        while (true) {
            Console.Write("Tell me something: ");
            var str = Console.ReadLine();
            if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(str)) {
                break;
            }
            strList.Add(str);
        }

        for (var i = 0; i < strList.Count; i++) {
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}. {1}", i + 1, strList[i]));
        }   
    }
}
```

**Example Usage:**

```
Tell me something: idk
Tell me something: C
Tell me something: A
Tell me something: 
1. idk
2. C
3. A
```

Try it **[here](https://repl.it/repls/SwelteringHoneydewAddon)**.